# Ember - Adding dynamic attributes to model inside serializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can we add dynamic attributes to model inside serializer.

I have created a model `entity`. I need this model for different type of entities. So for now I created an attribute `type` to identify which type of entity is that and the remaining attributes I need to create dynamically based on the response in serializer response handler. Is it possible?

**entity.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
   type: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**entity.js(Serialaizer)**

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   normalizeFindAllResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload) {
      var payloadData = {};
      payloadData.data = [];    
      payload.forEach(function(model) {
          // I will get the entity type and other attributes here
          // How can I define new attribute for model entity here
      }
   }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea. Your model should have structure. Maybe you need to figure it out differently

Comment: But in my case, dynamic attributes will come from server. So I can't define all in my model.

Comment: If it is attribute, it means you should handle it in CRUD operations. So you should implement each attribute like `attr` in ember data. And I think it is not a good practice. Maybe you need to change backend too

Comment: What does this " type " attribute contain. Maybe there are better ways to your problem.. Is it an integer?

Comment: Type will be entity types(eg:- employee, student etc.)

Comment: It is just a string like employee, student etc. to identify which type of entity it is..

Comment: @ManuBenjamin so you probably just have one Model? So you probably should not use `ember-data` at all. I rarely say this, but if you use a model framework you need to know which models you have. If you have an API to ask your server for all entity types with the attributes you could also build your models at runtime tho.